# wp7 application updates

Tags: windows-phone-7

For my WP7 app, I have a setting that I use to specify whether the application is running for the first time after an install.  This is useful to get some input from the user (one time only) when they use the app for the first time. (eg. birthday).

I am storing this setting whether the application first run is completed, in the Isolated Storage.  When I issue updates to this application later in the future, will the current settings get overwritten by the marketplace.  How does an update process work for an installed app?  Does it uninstall the application and re-install it?

Pratik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isolated storage is preserved between updates.

If you have any data structures that require updates to be compatible with the updated app software, this is your apps responsibility to maintain.

Comment: Mick, thanks for the clarification.  Does the marketplace allow you to increase/decrease the price?  Let's say, I publish my app for certain amount and based on feedback, may want to change the price with the next update, is that allowed?  Also, how much time does an app certification take?

Comment: People have been changing prices. Certification can be fairly quick providing you've taken care of everything... but by the terms they do allow themselves some time.

Comment: Man, you are fast in responding :) Thanks.